# How to open the file in new tab instead of saving by using Wt WResource

Tags: c++, wt

I am using Wt Widget WResouce to handle the problem on downloading file, I am using WAnchor to set the link to the resource.

When I click the link, I would like to open the file in the new tab on the web browser. However when I click the link, the file will be downloaded and saved.

Is there any way to open the file instead of saving it.

Thank you in advance.

Regards

Comment: How do you want to open your file? What kind of file do you use?

Comment: A html file. I have solved that. The WResource needed to be set as Inline and the Mimetype need to be set as text/html